# openpyxl - col_idx, column, column_letter in versions gt 2.5.8

Tags: openpyxl

With thousands of lines of code that uses openpyxl, we updated openpyxl (to version 2.6.2) and it appears that a change that affects backwards-compatibility has missed documentation.

1. Can someone (Charlie?) please confirm that `.column` - which formerly returned a letter - now returns a number, and a new method `.column_letter` must be used to return the letter? *(Did I understand that correctly from the docs?)*
2. In the new version, is there now any difference between what is returned from `.column` and `.col_idx`? *(Do these basically return the same thing, or is one zero-based and the other one-based? Or...?)*
3. To update our code, if we just search/replace the `.column` (expecting the column's letter) with `.column_letter` - is there anything else to be aware of? *(For E.G. Will the col ltr being returned by `.column_letter` be offset at all, or exactly the same as the old `.column` ?)*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there were some significant changes in OpenPyXL 2.6+ that somehow missed adequate  documentation.

An even larger change to be aware of -- because it also affects the `.column`/`.column_letter` methods -- is the functionality of `.merge_cells`.

It is no longer possible to use either `.column_letter` or `.col_idx` on a cell in a merged range - you must either use `.column` (for a number), or the `get_column_letter(cell)` method for a letter. ***(Note that you must import method `get_column_letter` from utils:***

```
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
```

Now, to answer your specific questions:

1) Yes, you must now use `.column_letter` (no longer `.column`) to get the column letter - but as mentioned above, it is safer to use `get_column_letter(cell)`.  And yes, `.column` will now return a number, not a letter.

2) Yes, `.column` now returns a number, exactly like `.col_idx`. **In fact, I recommend against using `.col_idx` any longer since it no longer works on cells within a merged cell range.**

3) Replace `.column` with `get_column_letter(cell)` instead of `.column_letter` due to changes with handling of merged cell ranges. So a simple search/replace would not be adviseable. Outside of merged cells, however, `.column_letter` now returns what `.column` used to do.

Comment: You keep saying to use `get_column_letter(cell)`.  But that errors, it does not accept a cell, one needs  `get_column_letter(cell.column)`, right?